Maven build creates a smaller jar when dependency is added locally with scope system and fails on startup
I have a java spring maven project which I build on my STS version 4. I want to add one of the dependecies as local and I added it as:
<dependency>
    <groupId>vzbiicommon</groupId>
    <artifactId>vzbiicommon</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath><path-to-my-file></systemPath>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xbean</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

But when I do a clean install, the output jar is almost 81,211KB.
But if I change the dependecy as below, the jar that is generated is 137,807KB:
<dependency>
            <groupId>vzbiicommon</groupId>
            <artifactId>vzbiicommon</artifactId>
            <version>2.4-FIX.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xbean</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Also the jar smaller jar fails on startup with below error:
[uuid=] - 01-Apr-2024 21:34:47 ERROR main org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at com.cmdb.smp.CmdbSmpApplication.main(CmdbSmpApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.xyz.smp.config.VzBIICommonClassObjectConfig] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@68de145]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hcs/cisco/www/HCSProvision_xsd/PartyRole
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hcs.cisco.www.HCSProvision_xsd.PartyRole
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        ... 25 more
[uuid=] - 01-Apr-2024 21:34:47 WARN main org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.xyz.smp.config.VzBIICommonClassObjectConfig] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@68de145]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at com.cmdb.smp.CmdbSmpApplication.main(CmdbSmpApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hcs/cisco/www/HCSProvision_xsd/PartyRole
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hcs.cisco.www.HCSProvision_xsd.PartyRole
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[cmdb-smp-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        ... 29 more


System dependencies are originally used to add jars, which are present in the JDK or JVM. The JVM is expected to provide these jars in the target/deployment runtime, and Maven won't bundle the dependencies with your war/jar.
System dependencies are deprecated and break the reproducibility of the build since the path is hardcoded. This will break CI builds.
So, don't use system dependencies.
Ref: System Dependencies
